# Retrieve a value inside a stored procedure and use it inside that stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
delimiter //
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDUREgetData(IN templateName VARCHAR(45),IN templateVersion VARCHAR(45),IN userId VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
set @version = CONCAT("SELECT saveOEMsData_answersVersion FROMsaveOEMsData WHERE saveOEMsData_templateName = '",templateName,"' ANDsaveOEMsData_templateVersion = ",templateVersion," AND saveOEMsData_userId= ",userId);
PREPARE s1 from @version;
EXECUTE S1;
END // delimiter ;
```

I am retrieving saveOEMsData_answersVersion, but I have to use it in an IF loop, as in if the version == 1, then I would use a query, else I would use something else. But I am not able to use the version. Could someone help with this?? I am only able to print but not able to use the version for data manipulation. The procedure works fine but I am unable to proceed to next step which is the if condition.

The if condition would have something like the below mentioned.

```
IF(ver == 1) THEN SELECT "1";
END IF;
```

Comment: Haven't you tried IF (@version =1) ... ?

Comment: is it if(@version==1) or if(@version=1)?? I am a newbie!

Comment: it is the second one: IF (@version =1)

Comment: the IF part is ok (except the = instead of == in the IF statement...), the syntax "SELECT ... INTO ver" is ok also so definetly the problem must be in the query

Comment: When I use the query, I am getting the required result. I am not sure if the assigning of parameters is fine? If the parameters are fine, then it has to be assigning using the SELECT INTO. :(.

Is there any other way around or do you find any fault in my syntaxes?? or do you have any examples?

Comment: @sai do not post code in comments, edit your post instead please.

Answer (score -1):

IF is allowed inside a Procedure, you can not use IF inside SQL, in SQL you can use CASE, but that doesn't have the same abilities.

Build a second procedure to handle the IF/Then for the results of getData

Comment: I want that IF to be inside the procedure only!